# Importing data from an HTML page to run Python code

Tags: python, html, flask, pyscript

I need to insert Python code so that it reads two variables from the data entry windows in HTML, as well as two excel files, runs the code when the button is clicked, and outputs the result of the program to a special .
How can this be done?

I tried using two frameworks Flask and Py Script. It is not possible to make the Python code take data and excel tables from the input windows and output the result to an html page.

df and df1 should read from the HTML page from the windows id="file-input-1" and id="file-input-2", respectively. your_choice from id="pipeline-input", and your_choice_year from id="data-input". when you click on the id="runCodeButton" button, the python code should be triggered and output the result result to the page

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/calculate', methods=['POST'])
def calculate():
df = pd.read_excel(request.files['file-input-1'], index_col=0)
df1 = pd.read_excel(request.files['file-input-2'], index_col=0)
your_choice = request.form['pipeline-input']
your_choice_year = int(request.form['data-input'])

name_list = df.index.tolist()

def f(your_choice, df, df1, name_list, your_choice_year):
...........
return render_template('index.html', result=result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal reproducible example in the question itself.

Comment: Also please properly indent your code.

Comment: The data of input fields are not queried based on the id, but rather based on the name attribute. The name attribute is the key with which the data in the dictionaries form and files can be accessed. Furthermore, it is not clear what you intend and how and where you run into a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't need PyScript for this task. Here is an example how to upload two excel files from html page to the python code using Flask and process it using Pandas.

**app.py**:

```
from flask import Flask, app, render_template, request
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)


def do_some_stuff(*args):
    return 42


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def calculate():
    if request.method == "POST":
        excel_file_1 = request.files["file-input-1"]
        if excel_file_1.filename == "":
            return render_template(
                "index.html", error_message="No file-input-1 input provided"
            )
        df1 = pd.read_excel(excel_file_1, index_col=0)

        excel_file_2 = request.files["file-input-2"]
        if excel_file_2.filename == "":
            return render_template(
                "index.html", error_message="No file-input-2 input provided"
            )
        df2 = pd.read_excel(excel_file_2, index_col=0)

        result = do_some_stuff(df1, df2)

        return render_template("index.html", result=result)
    return render_template("index.html")


app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8081)
```

As @detlef correctly mentioned you should use `name` attribute of the `<input>` instead of `id`.
**index.html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Calculator</title>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    {% if error_message %}
    Error: {{error_message}}
    {% endif %}
    <form action="/" method=post enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type=file name=file-input-1>
        <input type=file name=file-input-2>
        <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    Result: {{ result if result else "No result yet"}}
</body>

</html>
```

Note, this is not good solution but only the example how to deal with files in flask. Use [flashing](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/flashing/) rather to pass error to the template. Read how to correctly [save files in flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/fileuploads/) especially part about secure_filename. I have repeated myself twice for file reading logic but this code should be generalized to some function. This code simply calls `pd.read_excel` but it would be better to handle any possible errors here and notify user about it.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible to use PyScript to handle Excel files in the browser, if you choose to go that route. Here's an example with two upload `<input>`s and a button that prints the size of both:

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/releases/2023.05.1/pyscript.css">
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2023.05.1/pyscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <br><label for="file-1">Upload a first Excel file</label>
    <input type="file" id="file-1">

    <br><label for="file-2">Upload a second Excel file</label>
    <input type="file" id="file-2">

    <br><button py-click="calculate()">Click to Calculate</button>

    <py-config>
        packages = ['pandas', 'openpyxl']
    </py-config>

    <script type="py" src="test.py">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```py
from js import document, Uint8Array
from pyodide.ffi.wrappers import add_event_listener

import pandas as pd

async def storeFile(evt):
    file_list = evt.target.files
    first_item = file_list.item(0)

    #Get the data from the files arrayBuffer as an array of unsigned bytes
    array_buf = Uint8Array.new(await first_item.arrayBuffer())

    #IO wants a bytes-like object, so convert to bytearray first
    bytes_list = bytearray(array_buf)

    #Write the contents of the uploaded file to a file in the virtual FS that looks like "{id}.xls"
    file_name = evt.target.id + ".xls"
    with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
        f.write(bytes_list)

def calculate(*args):
    df = pd.read_excel("file-1.xls", index_col=0)
    df1 = pd.read_excel("file-2.xls", index_col=0)
    print(f"{df.size=}")
    print(f"{df1.size= }")

#Hook up event listeners to the inputs
add_event_listener(document.getElementById("file-1"), "change", storeFile)
add_event_listener(document.getElementById("file-2"), "change", storeFile)
```

Note that this is a *very* minimal example - there's no error handling around what happens if one/both of the files don't exist, are unparsable, etc.

Note too that this is for the current release of PyScript (`2023.05.1` at time of writing). An upcoming release changes a bit about how the `py-[event]` syntax works, but not much else.